# Missing color options in Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: visual-studio

When I go to Options > Fonts and Colors, some color options like User Types are missing.

Does anyone know why this would be?

---

#### Edit:

I also don't see the image in the About dialog. The one that's supposed to be at the top of the dialog like a banner.

Comment: In the dropdown for "Show Settings For", are you selecting "Text Editor"?

Comment: Yep, that's what I have selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure "show all settings" is checked (?) . I cold see it in my pro edition. Try resetting the settings : go to Tools -> import and export settings - > reset all settings 
[alt text http://shobankr.googlepages.com/untitled.JPG](http://shobankr.googlepages.com/untitled.JPG)

Comment: Thanks Shoban. I just looked at it and I don't have that option. By when I go to About dialog, it tells me I have installed pro upgrades, but not pro necessarily.

Comment: Thanks I did that too. It might be because maybe the IT installed incorrectly. I have to ask them to reinstall I guess.

Comment: IT Support always screws up things ;-) We face lot of issues.